# Constructor based dependency injection inject property based objects

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have two classes

```
Class B {
   @Resource
   C c;
}

Class A {
    private final B b;
    public A(B b) {
       this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Then class A is initialized using Spring through @Bean annotation as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfigHelper {

      @Bean
      public C getC() {
          return new C();
      }

      @Bean
      public B getB() {
          return new B();
      }

      @Bean
      public A getA() {
         return new A(getB());
      }
}
```

The problem that I end up with is C getting null in object of type B. Is there a solution to this problem? 
I have to get A initialized this way only as the B is the old code which I do not want to touch at this point of time.

Comment: Only a hint. Don't use the `getB` function in `getA` but add a `B` as an parameter -> `getA(B b)`

Comment: You created just a 'normal' (second) instance if B and this instance has no knowledge about dependency injection. If you use the method parameter, Spring injects the previous created instance (with the @Bean annotation).